# Ajax is "Getting" not "Posting"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use the Post Method in my jquery code but it using the Get method for some reason. I am working under the Wordpress Framework which have renamed the "$" function to jquery, which I then renamed to $j. Can anyone help me with this simple function?

```
  $j.ajax({
method: "POST",
url: "extension/marker.php",
data: "series=test",
dataType: "text",
success: function(data){ 
 $j("#text").text(data);
 console.log('success' + data);
 }
});
```

PHP File:

```
  <?php 

  if($_POST['series'] == "test")
   echo 'yay!';

  if($_GET['series'] == "test")
   echo 'boo!';

  ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`method: "POST"` should be `type: "POST"`.  See [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

> **type**
>   Default: 'GET'
>   *The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Note:
>   Other HTTP request methods, such as
>   PUT and DELETE, can also be used here,
>   but they are not supported by all
>   browsers.*

Comment: I always remember it to be "method" too... I suppose I've written too many <form> tags :)

Comment: ahhh! I suppose I overlooked that in the documents :(

Comment: @AKX: Yes.  IMO, it should have been named `method` to keep consistency with the parameter name of the `XMLHttpRequest.open` method and with the `method` attribute of forms.